# Get specific objects from Win32_PnpAllocatedResource

Tags: powershell, winapi, wmi

So I want to get those Pnp Devices, which use a given memory area (for example starting address = 655360). I'm using CIM/WMI and and the following command will get back resource and PnpEntity associations:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PnpAllocatedResource
```

But after that how can I get the Win32_PnpEntity associated to Win32_DeviceMemoryAddress which has the starting address 655360?

Answer (score 0):

So the field that you want is the `Antecedent` property. You only want the ones that refer to memory allocation, and of those you only want the ones that start at 655360. This is really basic stuff, and if you need to ask how to use a `Where` statement you probably need to go look on the internet on how to filter an array or something for a more detailed explanation to walk you through things.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PnpAllocatedResource | Where{$_.Antecedent -like 'Win32_DeviceMemoryAddress (StartingAddress = 655360)'}
```

That will only return the entries where the starting address is 655360. You should, in theory, be able to use `-eq` but for this case it doesn't seem to work as expected so the value may have hidden characters, or may be a value type other than `[String]` so we have to use `-Like` or `-Match` and in this case `-Like` works fine, and is less complicated.